How to add a certificate to a LinkedIn user account using API
Also what is the cost to use the LinkedIn API?
What is the cost of 1000 requests using the LinkedIn API?
Whether it is possible to give an app permission to post on the user's profile?
If it is possible to allow an app to add a certificate to a LinkedIn user's account?
